# Apache LimitRequestLine and log files

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, url

It's not particularly clear to me where apache should log what.
As an example I was passing a very long url to a virtualhost to see if Apache could avoid the overflow problem.

The directive handling the max number of bytes that will be allowed on the HTTP request-line is [LimitRequestLine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestline) by default setting this limit to 8190 bytes, anything longer than that should be rejected and "supposedly" and entry in `error.log` should be added.

I'm working on fail2ban conf and the [apache-overflow](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.10/config/jail.conf#L281) jail and indeed it suggests to look for this kind of error in the default `error.log`.

I've tested passing a very long url to my site (20000 random chars) and I could see a couple of entries logged to **error.log** as well as to **access.log**.

Repeating the same steps will no longer print the error to **error.log** and keep on printing it to **access.log**.

**Questions:**

1. What's the logic behind it, meaning what kind of log should go to which file? Should the `414 Request-URI Too Long` go to access.log or error.log?
2. what could be the possible cause of this weird behaviour of my error.log (Sometimes logging the 414, sometimes not). Misconfiguration or bug?